# Display variable data as month and year

Tags: python, date, monthcalendar

I have the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
df=pd.read_csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/08kuxi50d0xqnfc/demo.csv?dl=1")
df["date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df['date'] = df.date.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strftime(x,'%b')) # SHOWS date as MONTH
pvt_enroll=df.pivot_table(index='site', columns="date", values = 'baseline', aggfunc = {'baseline' : 'count'}, fill_value=0, margins=True) # Pivot_Table with enrollment by SITE by MONTH
pvt_enroll.to_csv("pivot_test.csv")
table_enroll_site_month = pd.read_csv('pivot_test.csv', encoding='latin-1')
table_enroll_site_month.rename(columns={'site':'Study Site'}, inplace=True)
table_enroll_site_month


Study Site      Apr     Jul      Jun    May      All
0      A         5.0    0.0     8.0      4.0    17.0
1      B         9.0    0.0     11.0     5.0    25.0
2      C         6.0    1.0     3.0      20.0   30.0
3      D         5.0    0.0     3.0      2.0    10.0
4      E         5.0    0.0     5.0      0.0    10.0
5    All         30.0   1.0     30.0     31.0   92.0
```

And wonder how to:
1.  Display months with year as 
    Apr16    Jul16     Jun16    May16
2. Is it possible to get same table without running this step (pvt_enroll.to_csv("pivot_test.csv")? I mean, can I get same result without needing to save to .csv file first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by using `%b%y` you can get 'Apr16' etc format.
I tried with the following code, without saving into .csv.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df=pd.read_csv("demo.csv")
df["date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strftime(x,'%b%y'))
pvt_enroll=df.pivot_table(index='site', columns="date", values = 'baseline', aggfunc = {'baseline' : 'count'}, fill_value=0, margins=True) # Pivot_Table with enrollment by SITE by MONTH
pvt_enroll.reset_index(inplace=True)
pvt_enroll.rename(columns={'site':'Study Site'}, inplace=True)
print(pvt_enroll)
```

And I got the output as follows

```
date Study Site  Apr16  Jul16  Jun16  May16  All
0             A      5      0      8      4   17
1             B      9      0     11      5   25
2             C      6      1      3     20   30
3             D      5      0      3      2   10
4             E      5      0      5      0   10
5           All     30      1     30     31   92
```

Comment: Thanks @Prince Francis